# Web Audio - Check supported formats

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

In HTML5 audio, I can do [this to find out if MP3 is supported](http://diveintohtml5.info/everything.html#audio-mp3):

```
var a = document.createElement('audio');
return !!(a.canPlayType && a.canPlayType('audio/mpeg;').replace(/no/, ''));
```

Is there a similar function for the Web Audio API? Or should I use the same function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same function.

Web Audio API does not support other formats than what is supported in the audio element.

Currently these are:

[image]

Source:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Audio

Just to get it correct as there is an error in this table: IE *do* support both Wav and Ogg.
See: https://www.microsoft.com/web/post/adding-audio-with-the-new-html5-audio-tag